# Unable to find Triggered Send in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

We are creating Send Definitions using API. However, i am unable to find these Send definitions in my marketing cloud business unit. I checked under the below path but the Send definition wasn't present : Email Studio -> Interactions tab, click on Messages >> Email >> Triggered Sends .
Could someone help me in locating it ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the relatively new [Transactional Messaging API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm)? If this is the case, you will not find any UI for managing those sends, and all operations, such as updating the send definitions when making changes to emails, will need to be performed via the API.

This new API should not be mistaken for the old Trigger Send Definition setup, as the performance is much higher and emails get sent faster compared to even high priority sends. It all comes with a price though:

> - You must use the API to configure the send definition and send    messages.
> - A singleton send request, which uses the recipient    attribute rather than the recipients attribute, must provide a unique messageKey as an ID.
> - The API doesn’t support send logging, triggered    send managed lists, suppression lists, or exclusion scripts.
> - To deduplicate at send time, use messageKey. Don’t use a primary key on    the triggered send data extension.

You can, however, use [getContentBlockByKey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbykey.htm) making the entire content of the email being fetched at sendtime, making the need for refreshing of the definition obsolete.

Any other changes will indeed require the API being called.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your response. If this is the case, then how can I fetch the Job ID as I need the job ID to query the customers who havent opened the mail in last 24 hours ?

Comment: You can fetch jobid(s) using the external key set when you created the transactional send: select jobid from _job where TriggeredSendCustomerKey = 'Lukas_transactional_test' - remember, you will get new jobid each time you PATCH the send definition.

Comment: @SourabMund - please remember to mark the answer as accepted, for the benefit of community